# If $f$ is an entire dunction such that $|f(z)|\le k|z| , \forall z \in \mathbb C$ ; $f(1)=i$ ; then how to find $f(i)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is an entire dunction such that $|f(z)|\le k|z| , \forall z \in \mathbb C$ ; $f(1)=i$ ; then how to find $f(i)$ ? I can do it if I know whether $\dfrac {f(z)}z$ is constant or not for $z \in \mathbb C$ .... Please help

Comment: Do you mean $|f(z)|\le k|z|$? Otherwise, you would have $|f(0)|<0$.

Comment: Hint: Cauchy's integral formula for the $2^{nd}$ derivative: $$f''(\zeta) = \frac{2!}{2\pi i}\oint_{C(0,R)} \frac{f(z)}{(z-\zeta)^3} dz$$ where $C(0,R)$ is a circle centered at $0$ with radius $R$ as large as you want.

Comment: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29#If_f_is_less_than_or_equal_to_a_scalar_times_its_input.2C_then_it_is_linear

Comment: @Paul: Yes, I was intending , but can we use Liouville's theorem ? $f(z)/z$ has a pole at $z=0$ ...

Comment: Here $f(0)=0$, as your condition follows, hence $z=0$ is not a pole for $f(z)/z$

Answer (score 1):

The function $g(z) =\frac{f(z)}{z} $ i entire and bounded hence it is constant . Thus $f(z) =a z$ and since $f(1) =i$ we obtain that $f(z) =iz,  $ therefore $f(i) =-1 .$

Comment: then how to define $g(0)$ ?

Comment: $$g(0)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{f(z)}{z}=f'(0)$$

Comment: $f(z) =0$ hence $f(z) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n z^n $ so we define $g(0) =a_1$